Is $\mathbb{R} / (0,1)$ connected in its quotient topology?
I am having lots of trouble with the following question:

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the Euclidean topology. Let $A$ be the open interval (0,1). Is $\mathbb{R} / A$ connected in its quotient topology?

I initially thought that yes, $\mathbb{R} / A$ would be connected. I reasoned that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, and if we consider the natural quotient map $q: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} / A$, then $q$ is continuous, and the continuous image of a connected set is connected.
However, I am having trouble fitting this into my intuition. If we think of $\mathbb{R} / A$ as identifying $(0,1)$ as a 'point' (say $x$ is the equivalence class of $(0,1)$). Then I do not see how $(-\infty,0] \cup \{x\} \cup [1,\infty)$ is connected.
Is my initial reasoning correct? If so, where am I failing in my intuition?

I think you're noticing that $x$ is an isolated point, which in a $T_1$ space would witness a disconnection ($T_1$ means points are closed, so an open-and-closed singleton disconnects the space).
But this quotient is only $T_0$ (points can be distinguished by open sets); every neighborhood of $0$ contains $x$, and every neighborhood of $1$ contains $x$ also. So having an isolated point need not disconnect the space (and does not, since the continuous image of connected is always connected).

Yes, if $X$ is connected then so is its every quotient.

Then I do not see how $(-\infty,0] \cup \{x\} \cup [1,\infty)$ is connected.

Because neither $(-\infty, 0]$ nor $[1,\infty)$ is open in the quotient topology. While $\{x\}$ is not closed (the space is not $T_1$). You basicaly wrote $\mathbb{R}/A$ as a union of an open subset and two closed subsets. Which doesn't say much. All of them would have to be open (or all closed) for that to work.
